# Numpy.where: very slow with conditions from two different arrays

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have three arrays of type numpy.ndarray with dimensions (n by 1), named  *amplitude*, *distance* and *weight*. I would like to use selected entries of the *amplitude* array, based on their respective *distance*- and *weight*-values. For example I would like to find the indices of the entries within a certain distance range, so I write:

```
index = np.where( (distance<10) & (distance>=5) )
```

and I would then proceed by using the values from `amplitude(index)`.
This works perfectly well as long as I only use one array for specifying the conditions. When I try for example

```
index = np.where( (distance<10) & (distance>=5) & (weight>0.8) )
```

the operation becomes super-slow. Why is that, and is there a better way for this task? In fact, I eventually want to use many conditions from something like 6 different arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but perhaps `numpy` is broadcasting your arrays? If the arrays are the exact same shape, then `numpy` won't broadcast them:

```
>>> distance = numpy.arange(5) > 2
>>> weight = numpy.arange(5) < 4
>>> distance.shape, weight.shape
((5,), (5,))
>>> distance & weight
array([False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

But if they have different shapes, and the shapes are broadcastable, then it will. `(n,)`, `(n, 1)`, and `(1, n)` are all arguably "n by 1" arrays, they aren't all the same:

```
>>> distance[None,:].shape, weight[:,None].shape
((1, 5), (5, 1))
>>> distance[None,:]
array([[False, False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> weight[:,None]
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
>>> distance[None,:] & weight[:,None]
array([[False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

In addition to returning undesired results, this could be causing a big slowdown if the arrays are even moderately large:

```
>>> distance = numpy.arange(5000) > 500
>>> weight = numpy.arange(5000) < 4500
>>> %timeit distance & weight
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.17 us per loop
>>> %timeit distance[:,None] & weight[None,:]
10 loops, best of 3: 48.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the arrays all have the same shape and size. n is ~5e4, and the shape is (n by 1), so I should not have the broadcasting problem... what else could be wrong?

Comment: Then I can't reproduce this problem. There must be something unusual about your arrays -- edit your question above to show `a.shape`, `a.strides`, and `a.dtype` for each array `a` in question. Also, say more about your actual code, if the above is just a simplified example. The only other possibility I can think of is that your machine is running out of memory, but that seems unlikely for 50,000-item arrays.